# how to know record exist against relation of table in SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database, vb.net

I have 100 tables in a SQL Server database. Each table has relations with the `Customer` table, and each table has a column `CustomerId`.

If I attempt to delete a customer from the table, then I get an error.

So I want to check each table to see if that `CustomerId` exists in that table or not.

Is this possible in SQL Server? Return me only Yes/No if the record is present in other table?

Comment: what error you get? if it is do you have selected cascade in relation ship?

Comment: Can you give us a short example of your tables and what exactly are you trying to do ?

Comment: The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_FinishMaterialItem_Customer". The conflict occurred in database "PakPackages_Live", table "dbo.FinishMaterialItem", column 'CustomerCode'.

Comment: know i am Checking each table one by one conditionally. But this not proper way

Answer (score 0):

You can create small function to check wether the id exists or not.

Try This:

```
   bool IsIdExist(int id)
    {
        using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Connection String Here"))
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select count(*) from customer where id=@id", con))
        {
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
            con.Open();
            int rows = Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar());
            if (rows > 0)
                return true;

            return false;
        }            
    }
```

You can call the above function as below:

```
if(IsIdExist(300))
{
//id exists
}
else
{
//id does not exist
}
```

Comment: No Sir this not my requirement. I want Syntax of Sql Server that how to know Primary key refrence on relaional table. if record is exist YES/No Only

Comment: @Salman: could you please explain your requirement with example?

Comment: I have 100 table in Sql Server. One table is Customer's table .ok . Now each 100 table have column CustomerID and Relation with Customer primary key to each table forin  key and. Suppose a Customer "ABC" with id of 1 and these 1 id pass each 100 table . Know if i want run Qurey Delete from Customer where CustomerID=1 then its could not be delete becasue its relation id pass on other 100 table. My Question is that How to know there 1 Id pass on any relation Table just return me true or Not Simple :). But i cant like check each talbe one by one